# Kotlin OkHttp3 Using 'of(Map<String, String>): Headers' is an error. function moved to extension

Tags: kotlin, okhttp

The code below gives the error : Using 'of(Map): Headers' is an error. function moved to extension.

```
val mapH = mapOf (Pair("Content-Disposition",
          "file; filename=\"$encodedFileName\""),
          Pair("Content-Transfer-Encoding",
          "binary"))

    val headers = Headers.of (mapH)
```

Having read the documentation here https://square.github.io/okhttp/upgrading_to_okhttp_4/#extension-functions, I tried :

```
      val headers = headersOf(mapH)
and also 
      val headers = mapH.toHeaders()
```

and got the errors : Unresolved reference: for headersOf and toHeaders. Why ?

Comment: You need to import the extension functions separately

Comment: I gave the two functions as an example. They are not used together in the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
import okhttp3.Headers.Companion.toHeaders
```

Comment: Could you comment this solution ? Any documentation ? I have other similar issues without any solution.

Comment: I got the documentation here : https://square.github.io/okhttp/upgrading_to_okhttp_4/#extension-functions